# Should "doubleclick" and "google-dfp" tags be merged?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

- [doubleclick](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/doubleclick) × 6
- [google-dfp](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-dfp) × 11

Google bought doubleclick in 2007.  Google DFP stands for "doubleclick for publishers".

Comment: Seeing no objections, I went ahead with this tag merge.

Answer (score 1):

While Doubleclick as a company had more than just a ad server product, the usage of the "doubleclick" tag on this site refers to DFP in every case.  These tags should be merged into "google-dfp".